# Is it possible to have a single date exposed filter with date range?

Tags: 7, views

[image]

In my existing exposed filter, I have two field (Start and End Date) filter, Is it possible to create as one field?

Comment: Please, Could you add tag 7 or 8 depends of the version you are asking for? :)

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is a module for that, [views_between_dates_filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_between_dates_filter), from module:

> This Views filter provides the between date functionality you've been looking for by answering the question: "What events are on this date?" It displays all content (comparing start and end dates) occurring on a specified date.
>
> It compares two date fields with one supplied date. Effectively it is the opposite of the standard Date Views "between" operator, which compares one date field with two supplied dates.